# Multiple webservice calls

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-farm

I have a webservice (ASP.NET) deployed on a webfarm. A client application consumes it on daily basis. The problem is that some of its calls are duplicated (with difference of milliseconds). For example I have a function Foo(string a,string b). The client app calls this webmethod as Foo('test1','test2') once but my log shows that it is being called twice or sometimes 3 or 4 times randomly. Is this anything wrong with the webfarm or the code? Note that the webmethod has simple straighfarward insert and update statements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue will be with the webfarm. How do you identify the service? What is the end point looks like?

Comment: My webservice URL is like this.
http://mysite.com/webservice/webservicename.asmx
I simply insert a log entry in a table when a method is called. That log shows that the function is called multiple times (random with difference of miliseconds). Same service has been tested on a single server which works fine but on webfarm it is duplicating. :(